# angular .focus is not a function when working with native elemtn

Tags: angular

Hi I have a line in angular I cant for the life of me figure out whats not working. My friend asked for help with this as the errors causing data to not display but im not sure where the problem is at.

Error Message:

```
this.ccavtabSelected.nativeElement.classlist.contains(...).focus is not a function
```

@ViewChild('ccavTabSelected') ccavTabSelected: ElemenRef (this is where the ccavtab variable is set)

full line that is not working:

```
setTimeout()) = > {
this.ccavtabSelected.nativeElement.classlist.contains('ccav-tab-container-selected active').focus();
}, 20);
```

Code for the entire function:

```
selectTab(tabIndex: any) {

    try {

        // To do

        if (event.currentTarget['parentElement'].getElementsByClassName('active').length > 0) {

            event.currentTarget['parentElement'].getElementsByClassName('active')[0].classList.remove('active');

        }

        if (tabIndex == TabCategory.ACCOUNTSUMMARY) {

            event.currentTarget['classList'].add('active');

            setTimeout(() => {

                if (this.ccavTabSelected.nativeElement.classlist.contains('ccav-tab-container-selected active')) {

                    this.ccavTabSelected.nativeElement.focus();

                  }

               

            }, 20);

            console.log(this.ccavTabSelected.nativeElement.classList)

            this.isAccountSummaryActive = true;

            this.isDebitcardActive = false;

            this.isMerchantServicesActive = false;

            if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {

                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

            }

            this.accSummaryCommonService.updateTabInContext(TabCategory.ACCOUNTSUMMARY);



        } else if (tabIndex == TabCategory.DEBITCARD) {

            event.currentTarget['classList'].add('active');

            setTimeout(() => {

                this.ccavTabSelected.nativeElement.classList.contains('ccav-tab-container-selected active').focus();

            }, 20);

            this.isAccountSummaryActive = false;

            this.isDebitcardActive = true;

            this.isMerchantServicesActive = false;

            if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {

                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

            }

            this.accSummaryCommonService.updateTabInContext(TabCategory.DEBITCARD);

        }

        else if (tabIndex == TabCategory.MERCHANTSERVICES) {

            event.currentTarget['classList'].add('active');

            setTimeout(() => {

                this.ccavTabSelected.nativeElement.classList.contains('ccav-tab-container-selected active').focus();

            }, 20);

            this.isAccountSummaryActive = false;

            this.isDebitcardActive = false;

            this.isMerchantServicesActive = true;

            if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {

                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

            }

            this.accSummaryCommonService.updateTabInContext(TabCategory.MERCHANTSERVICES);



        }

        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();

    } catch (err) {

        this.handleErrorMessage("selectTab()", err.message);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it is not a function since `contains` returns a boolean.

Instead try:

```
setTimeout()) = > {
   if (this.ccavtabSelected.nativeElement.classlist.contains('ccav-tab-container-selected active')) {
     this.ccavtabSelected.nativeElement.focus();
   }
}, 20);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I tried implementing it. This is the error message im receviwing when I change the code to the line you suggested.   cannont read properties of undefined (reading 'contains') any idea about this?

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example. Or at least complete code.  Like that this.ccavtabSelected is not defined.

Comment: I added the remaning code for that function that contains the broken line. The entire file is to big to post here but could provide other details if anything needed.

Comment: I would add a console.log inside of the setTimeout but before the if. console.log(this.ccavtabSelected) . Also, please post HTML related to this element.